# $P(E(X))$ for multiple IID Gamma Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, gamma-distribution

Losses relating to a type of insurance policy follow a gamma distribution with mean $30,000$ and $\alpha = 2$. For a sample of $100$ policy claims, calculate an approximate probability that the mean loss size is less than $27,000$.
 Answer $= 0.0787$ but I don't know why or how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outline: 1) Let $X$ be the sample mean. Look up the variance $\sigma^2$ of the gamma. 2) Then $X$ has mean $30000$, variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{100}$. 3) Use the normal approximation to $X$ to approximate  the probability that $X$ is less than $27000$.

Comment: Thank you! That worked out!

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy that the decision to leave much of the work to you turned out well.